# javascript: passing parameter with special characters to function without being replaced

Tags: javascript, function

I need to pass to javascript function some data that has special characters like

```
#228;
```

A full string will look like this

```
Bundesland K&#228;rnten
```

My javascript function looks like this

```
function my_fumc(arg){
    console.log(arg);
}
```

If i call this function in the following way

```
my_fumc('Bundesland K&#228;rnten')
```

I get in  console

```
Bundesland Kärnten
```

Instead of

```
Bundesland K&#228;rnten
```

So, the

```
K&#228;
```

being replaced.

I tried different things to solve this problem. 1.Passing a variable as parameter

```
my_var = 'Bundesland K&#228;rnten';
my_fumc(my_var)
```

It works but i don't think it's a good solution.2. I also tried using encodeURI() function like

```
my_fumc(encodeURI('Bundesland K&#228;rnten'))
```

As a result i get:

```
Bundesland%20K%C3%A4rnten
```

I prepared a very simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcx412o0/2/) to show how javascript behaves when passing special characters to function.

Please, help me find a solution.

Comment: is it possible for you to set this string value ("Bundesland K&#228;rnten") to some data- attribute of button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode html entities in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: This might be browser-specific...it's interesting that it treats the string literal differently if it's put in a variable first, because on Chromium for Linux they both display the same result (with the ä).

Comment: This is not how js behaves, but how html does. Rule of thumb : don't use html `onEvent` attributes, for reasons like this. If you simply did `button.addEventListener("click", function(){myfunc('Bundesland K&#228;rnten')});` you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @Akshay Chawla as you advised i tried  data- attribute but i still doesn't work as it should. See jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aucrw5hx/

Comment: @user2265529 are you try with `decodeURI()` for decode your string

Comment: is there any restriction to use jquery ?

Comment: @Akshay Chawla jquery can be used

Comment: when you run your page, just look at that specific button element using 'Inspect element'. Issue is with HTML only, that specific special characters get converted into alphabets when HTML has been rendered, so that's why JavaScript is printing alphabets.

Comment: is it possible for you to assign this string value directly into an JavaScript variable ?

Comment: @Akshay Chawla ,It is one of the methods that i may use if no simpler solutions will be found.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Kaiido, the problem is more to do with how HTML works.

An option might be something more like:

```js
var txt = ["Bundesland K&#228;rnten 01", "Bundesland K&#228;rnten 02"];

function my_func(e){
 var idx = (this.id == "t1") ? 0 : 1;
 console.log(txt[idx]);
}

window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById("t1").addEventListener("click",my_func,true);
 document.getElementById("t2").addEventListener("click",my_func,true);
}
```

```html
<button id="t1">button 1</button>
<button id="t2">button 2</button>
```