# A plain JavaScript way to decode HTML entities, works on both browsers and Node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, decode

How to decode HTML entities like `&nbsp;` `&#39;` to its original character?

In browsers we can create a DOM to do the trick ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery/1395954#1395954)) or we can use some libraries like [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he)

In NodeJS we can use some third party lib like [html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities)

What if we want to use plain JavaScript to do the job?

There are many similar questions and useful answers in stackoverflow but I can't find a way works both on browsers and Node.js. So I'd like to share my opinion.

I have posted my opinion as an answer below. I hope it can be a helping hand for someone. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript

This should really work. Ensure encoding is the same

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he

Comment: The [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) package solves this by following the HTML spec instead of relying on a manually maintained dictionary.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There are many similar questions and useful answers in stackoverflow but I can't find a way works both on browsers and Node.js. So I'd like to share my opinion.

**For html codes like `&nbsp;` `&lt;` `&gt;` `&#39;` and even Chinese characters.**

I suggest to use  this function. (Inspired by some other answers)

```
function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
    var translate_re = /&(nbsp|amp|quot|lt|gt);/g;
    var translate = {
        "nbsp":" ",
        "amp" : "&",
        "quot": "\"",
        "lt"  : "<",
        "gt"  : ">"
    };
    return encodedString.replace(translate_re, function(match, entity) {
        return translate[entity];
    }).replace(/&#(\d+);/gi, function(match, numStr) {
        var num = parseInt(numStr, 10);
        return String.fromCharCode(num);
    });
}
```

This implement also works in Node.js environment.

`decodeEntities("&#21704;&#21704;&nbsp;&#39;&#36825;&#20010;&#39;&amp;&quot;&#37027;&#20010;&quot;&#22909;&#29609;&lt;&gt;") //哈哈 '这个'&"那个"好玩<>`

As a new user, I only have 1 reputation :(

I can't make comments or answers to existing posts so that's the only way I can do for now.

**Edit 1**

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39243641/8001881) answer works even better than mine. Although no one gave him up vote.

Comment: This will miss a lot of html-entities, sunch as `&rdquo;` `&uuml;` `&scaron;` etc. The comprihensive list of all html-entities is quite long: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

Comment: This is incorrect. Since there are two `replace`s, "&amp;#41;" will be decoded as "A" and not as "&#41;" as it should be. I still upvoted but because the linked answer is correct.

Comment: Worked for me to replace #8217; was looking for about 15 minutes, thanks

Comment: IMPORTANT! This is vulnerable to XSS attacks for user-inputted content. `&amp;#60;` is converted into `<` due to there being two separate `replace` calls.

Comment: It also misses hexadecimal values, such as `&#xA0;`.