# How to validate malicious input?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying avoid malicious input values in nodejs any npm package is there.can any one help me on this.

Thanks Ram

Comment: What do you qualify as "malicious input" ? If you want to avoid XSS, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44195856/3670132) should fit. If you want to avoid SQL injection, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sanitize-escape) and find it very convenient.

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sanitize-escape`

`npm i --save express-sanitize-escape`