# data is break in http post request when there is & sign in json string

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http, post

I have one json string , string is below.

```
 {  
   "assigned_to":1,
   "type":0,
   "email":[  
      {  
         "value":"mobile@gmail.com",
         "is_primary":1,
         "type":1,
         "type_id":1
      }
   ],
   "first_name":"Mr Mobile",
   "salutation_id":1,
   "links":[  
      {  
         "company":"Mobile",
         "relation":"CEO & Founder",
         "cmp_id":1
      }
   ],
   "phone":[  
      {  
         "code":"",
         "value":"",
         "is_primary":1,
         "phone_type":"1",
         "country_code_value":""
      }
   ],
   "photo":"",
   "last_name":""
}
```

When i pass this data using http and  post method then string is break after & sign.

My http post request code is like this.

> NOTE: JSON.stringify(this.formData) returns above string

```
$http.post(APP.API + 'contacts', 'data=' + JSON.stringify(this.formData)).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {


                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        // debugger;
                        Notification.error(data.msg);
                    });
```

What is passed in this request , please find below screen shot of the network.[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nz6h.png)

This screen shot is after remove 'data=+' remove from request: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw3iJ.png)

data is break after & in relation key.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove `'data=' +`

Comment: i tried , same problem

Comment: just a moment , i also share screenshot of after remove `data=`

Comment: In that case you'd need to refer to the documentation of the API to see what format it expects data in. Also, check the console to see exactly what the error returned is

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18750001/1595977

Comment: after save unicode in database , should i get & in response ??

Comment: Actually I don't understand your question.

Comment: is there any problem with `content-type` ??

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. Do you have any interceptors in your code?

Comment: I once encountered same problem as yours, I solved that by using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in my header part of `index.html`

Answer (score 1):

use encodeURIComponent() function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: there is problem with content-type , content-type is `x-www-form-urlencode` , i change this to `application/json` and it is working now