# Unescape cyrillyc characters escaped like &#xXXX;

Tags: javascript, utf-8, escaping

i have a following problem: 
I am parsing a website with Node-Red "html request"-component. It returns a UTF-8 String representation of a web page, which i try to process afterwards in Javascript function. My problem ist that strings in some elements on the page are being encoded like

```
&#x43F;&#x440;&#x438;&#x432;&#x435;&#x442;
```

which should actualy say

```
привет
```

What kind of escaping is that? It looks like unicode, but with "&#x" instead of "/u0". How can i make the text human-readable again using javascript?

Comment: They are *HTML Entities*, the duplicate has a function to convert to a string.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works as planed now:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var str='&#x43F;&#x440;&#x438;&#x432;&#x435;&#x442;';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
var new_str=div.firstChild.nodeValue;
console.log(new_str);
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I want to describe my solution here. As Node-Red uses server-side javascript and misses all the browser-site javascript features like DOM-Parser i have used  this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript