# How to embed JSON in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, json

I have a JSON array:

`info = [{"name":"abc", "rank" : 1},{"name":"xyz", "rank":2},{"name":"pqr", "rank":3}];`

and I am trying to pass it as an input value to a hidden field using `jQuery` and send it to the server with a `POST` request.

```
$('<form action="/info/saveAll" method="POST"/>')
        .append($('<input type="hidden" name="info" value="' + JSON.stringify(info) + '">'))
        .appendTo($(document.body))
        .submit();
```

At the server end, I am accessing the value of `info` as:

```
router.route('/saveAll')
    .post((req, res) => {
       let info = JSON.parse(req.body.info);
       console.log(info); //SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    })
```

If I don't `stringify` the array before submit, then the `typeof info` still returns string inside the post and when I try to `parse` the string type I get syntax error like `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`.

I know this can be done by just doing it through an ajax post request, but I wanted a work around that does not involve an ajax request.

Any help would be great.

Comment: @Emma it did not work with trim, or if I use concat. and the post you suggested has ajax request. I mentioned in my question that I don't want to use ajax request.

Comment: @Emma the problem is that the generated HTML is corrupted, because a JSON string can contain reserved characters like `"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't simply concatenate a JSON string into HTML, because it can contain reserved characters, like `"`, that need to be quoted. Just comment out the `.submit()` and check the hidden `input` field your code added to the DOM with DOM Inspector in your browser developer tools. You'll see that the `value=` attribute is corrupted.

The solution is simple: use `encodeURI()` instead, i.e.

```javascript
.append($(
    '<input type="hidden" name="info" value="' +
    encodeURI(JSON.stringify(info)             + 
    '\'>'))
```

and

```javascript
let info = JSON.parse(decodeURI(req.body.info));
```

Now you'll see that the attribute is shown as valid JSON string in the DOM inspector. When you select "Edit as HTML" menu on your hidden `input` element you'll see a quoted string in the HTML text for the `value=` attribute.

From my manual test with Firefox:

### Incorrect

```javascript
const info = {
          test: "somestring",
          html: '<input type="hidden" value="&"/>',
      };
$('#demo').append($(
        '<input type="hidden" value="' +
        JSON.stringify(info))          +
        '">'));
```

The generated HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" value="{" test":"somestring","html":"<input="">
```

### Correct

```javascript
const info = {
          test: "somestring",
          html: '<input type="hidden" value="&"/>',
      };
$('#demo').append($(
        '<input type="hidden" value="'   +
        encodeURI(JSON.stringify(info))) +
        '">'));
```

The generated HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" value="%7B%22test%22:%22somestring%22,%22html%22:%22%3Cinput%20type=%5C%22hidden%5C%22%20value=%5C%22&amp;%5C%22/%3E%22%7D">
```

Another option is to use a HTML entities encode/decode method, f.ex. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript), but the provided answers seem to be more cumbersome than my solution. It would be easier to use a npm module instead, e.g. [entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/entities).

---

### Or simply...

... don't rely on HTML string parsing and let jQuery do all the work. It also removes the need to use `decodeURI()` on the server side:

```javascript
const info  = {
          test: "somestring",
          html: '<input type="hidden" value="&"/>',
      },
      input = $('<input type="hidden"/>')
          .val(JSON.stringify(info));
$('#demo')
      .append(input);
```

The generated HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" value="{&quot;test&quot;:&quot;somestring&quot;,&quot;html&quot;:&quot;<input type=\&quot;hidden\&quot; value=\&quot;&amp;\&quot;/>&quot;}">
```

Comment: My initial solution only worked for simple cases. Updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: There is actually a much simpler approach. Updated my answer with another solution,

Comment: this works perfectly ! I now have a much better and clear understanding.