# JQuery html() not support < symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

When changing the content with `.html()` there is an issue not showing the whole data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn2").click(function() {
        $("#test2").html("<b>Hello < world!</b>");
      });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="test2">Result here</p>
  <button id="btn2">Click for result</button>
</body>

</html>
```

---

The result I get is: `Hello`

I need the result to be: `Hello < world!`

This is just a sample.

Comment: You probably need to escape that `<`, have you tried `&lt;`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&lt;` in your snippet to be explicit but that was not your issue, your JS issue was not closing of `jQuery.ready` function in your snippet.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#test2").html("<b>Hello &lt; world!</b>");
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test2">Result here</p>
    <button id="btn2">Click for result</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTML entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) `&lt;` to replace the `<` symbol.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#btn2").click(function()
    {
        $("#test2").html("<b>Hello &lt; world!</b>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test2">Result here</p>
<button id="btn2">Click for result</button>
```

If you don't have control over the input text, then you can [Encode html entities in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript). As mentioned on that link, you can create a method to encode the input `str`:

```js
function encodeStr(str)
{
    return str.replace(
        /[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim,
        i => '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';'
    );
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#btn2").click(function()
    {
        let text = "Hello < world!";
        $("#test2").html("<b>" + encodeStr(text) + "</b>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test2">Result here</p>
<button id="btn2">Click for result</button>
```

Comment: This is not supported in IE

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle suggests your code works (to a degree): https://jsfiddle.net/6y2s0ue9/

You may just want to correct the `$(document).ready` to close, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#test2").html("<b>Hello < world!</b>");
    });
});
```

On click of the button, it replaces "Result here" with "**Hello < world!**"

Answer (score 0):

With `.html()` the code will read the `<` symbol as a tag so it will print nothing so other answers can solve that.. But with `.text()` it will read as it is so no need to replace symbol with `&lt;`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#test2").html($('<b></b>').text("Hello < world!"));
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test2">Result here</p>
    <button id="btn2">Click for result</button>
</body>
</html>
```