# Axios - replacing accents by &eacute;, for example

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios

[EDIT] FIXED: I deal with it on javascript side (vuejs), using v-html="blabla"

I figured out that in many of my axios requests, I get é replaced by é for example, the accents are not correctly decoded.

I can see that I can use html_entity_decode on php side or replace it afterwards in javascript but I am wondering if maybe there is an issue with my axios requests, or I could add something in the call so that this doesn't happen? Cause it happens at many places...

Here is an example of an axios call

```
getResults: function(){

            let filters = {
                id: this.id,
                year: this.year,
                page: this.page,
                q: this.query
            };
            axios.post('/data/results', filters).then(
                response => {
                    this.results=response.data;
                }
            );
```

Comment: hello, [you should have look on this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, I found an easier solution actually ;) (and edited the question)

Comment: Very nice @Gertrude, would you please write a short answer and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I deal with it on javascript side (vuejs), using v-html="blabla"
Or if needed outside the html part, using decodeURI(blabla)