# Selective Rendering of Plain HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please consider the code below.

Here are what I need to happen:

1.) The html tag from variable `msg_raw` will be rendered as plain html.

2.) The html tag from variable `message` will be applied, which would mean that the output display will have a red colored `ABC` text and blue colored `<b>DEF</b>` text, like so:

```
ABC           <-- red colored text
<b>DEF</b>    <-- blue colored text
```

```js
var msg_raw = '<b>DEF</b>';
var message = '<div class="red_text">ABC</div>';
message += '<div class="blue_text">' + msg_raw + '</div>';

$('#some_ID').html(message);
```

```css
.red_text{ color: red; }
.blue_text{ color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_ID"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After inserting the `<b>` as HTML, insert the text that needs to be inside it with `.text`:

```js
var msg_1 = '<span class="red_text">ABC</span>';

$('#some_ID').html('<b/>');
$('#some_ID > b').text(msg_1);
```

```css
.red_text{ color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_ID"></div>
```

For a more dynamic option, you can replace all characters with a special meaning in HTML with their HTML entity in the `msg_raw` before concatenating it into `message`:

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript
var encodedStr = rawStr => rawStr.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
   return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});

var msg_raw = '<b>DEF</b>';
var message = '<div class="red_text">ABC</div>';
message += '<div class="blue_text">' + encodedStr(msg_raw) + '</div>';

$('#some_ID').html(message);
```

```css
.red_text{ color: red; }
.blue_text{ color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_ID"></div>
```

Comment: This solved my question, however, it seems like the question i created does not exactly match my actual codes. would you mind me editing my question?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: exactly what I needed, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

you can also use < and > instead < and > :

```js
var msg_1 = '&lt span class="red_text"&gtABC &lt/span&gt';
var msg_2 = '<b>' + msg_1 + '</b>';

$('#some_ID').html(msg_2);
```

```css
.red_text{ color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_ID"></div>
```