# Why is innerHTML truncating my string (and how do I fix it)?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have two simple strings I want to output (both coming from user input).  The `console.log` says that they are properly received by JavaScript into their respective variables, but when I output them via `innerHTLM`, the first is truncated at the "<" symbol.

JavaScript

```
var content1 = "Dog- Happy<Hungry", content2 = "Dog- Happy<2Hungry"
console.log(content1,content2)
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = content1 + "<br>" + content2
```

Output

```
Dog- HappyDog- Happy<2Hungry
```

Expected Output

```
Dog- Happy<Hungry
Dog- Happy<2Hungry
```

The input is from users and I want them to be able to use the "<" symbol, as it is a common symbol for this type of input.  I am guessing that the "<" is being seen as the beginning of an HTML tag, though I am not sure.  How do I solve this, so that they can use the "<" symbol?

Here is a JSFiddle if it is helpful:  https://jsfiddle.net/m79dca3p/

[Encode html entities in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript/18750001#18750001) does not help as those responding are split on the best solution, thus it is still an open debate and not a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encode html entities in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: Consider using `&lt;` instead of `<`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox — It's user input.

Comment: @Quentin In that case the character could be swapped out?

Comment: I found this one that seems to be similar, also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript.  Is that the recommended solution, to do a bunch of `.replace()` lines?

Comment: @esqew It seems like people responding to that page are split on what to do.  The first answer has over a hundred upvotes, but the second answer, likewise with many upvotes, says "The currently accepted answer has several issues."

Answer (score 4):

`<` is how you start a tag in HTML, and since you use `innerHTML` the input is treated as HTML.

If you want input to be treated as plain text, use a mechanism that deals in text and not one that deals in HTML.

```js
const content1 = "Dog- Happy<Hungry";
const content2 = "Dog- Happy<2Hungry";
const output = document.getElementById("output");
output.append(document.createTextNode(content1));
output.append(document.createElement('br'));
output.append(document.createTextNode(content2));
```

```html
<div id=output></div>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `.append()`.  Does it deal with these symbols correctly without having to swap them out?

Comment: No. `createTextNode` does. You can see the result in the live demo in the answer.

Answer (score -3):

Just use innerText instead of innerHTML and add your `<br>`separateley

Comment: I don't think `innerText` respects a break tag.

Comment: How would you add the `<br>` between two pieces of text in the same text node?

Comment: @inetphantom Can you comment on the advantages of innerText?