# I just want to replace £ with &pound; in javascript / node

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a stupidly simple question.
I'm pulling some content from a site using request in nodes and the pound signs are displaying as Â£.

Page encoding issue, I thought. I've tried everything like changing the charset meta tags on my page, encoding and decoding the incoming code, using iconv to decode the incoming response. Loads and loads of things I've tried. All failed.

So my final last-ditch attempt is to replace £ with `&pound;`.

I've tried lots of variations of

```
string.replace(/£/g, '&pound;')
```

But this just replaces £ with literally `&pound;` on my output code.
Is there are way to achieving this ridiculously simple sounding thing?

Thanks.

Comment: [This could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript). I agree that is a meta config of the page. What `<head>` has the page?

Comment: I've tried iso-8859-1, UTF-8 and Windows-1252. Windows-1252 and iso-8859-1, the problem was the same. UTF-8 made it worse. ÂÂ£.

Comment: Would you mind to check the string bytes with `Buffer.from(string)`. This should show the chars that are composing the string and where could hide invisible ones

Comment: Doesn't mean a lot to me, but here is an example. <Buffer 36 31 35 2e 38 38>. Sorry my screwup. That was after I remove the £ altogether. This is the proper one. <Buffer c2 a3 36 31 35 2e 38 38>

Comment: I was wrong, the string is clean. `Buffer.from([0xc2, 0xa3, 0x36, 0x31, 0x35, 0x2e, 0x38, 0x38]).toString('utf8')` [C2A3](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A3/) is the pound char byte rapresentation. I cant replicate setting `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove Â£ in string replace, and put again using [intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/orphaned/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

```
let x = string.replace(/£/g, '')
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(x));
// expected output: "123.456,79 €"
```

Comment: op wants to replace `£` with `£` not `£` with `€`, reread the question

Comment: Don't think this will work anyhow. It's a block of text I'm trying to place the pound signs with, not just a monetary value. Thanks for the response.