# How do I display snippets of HTML code in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

For example I have a template and in that template I want to show

```
<div></div>
```

I want it to be displayed as above rather than rendering the actual div

Comment: See this from the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Answer (score 3):

according to the Angular.js documentation for [$sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize):

there are 3 options for ng-bind.

1. `ng-bind-html` - will output sanitized html, not escaped, which will render normally.  JavaScript and other "unsafe" elements are stripped.  `<div>Raw HTML</div>` will render `Raw HTML`.
2. `ng-bind-unsafe` - will bypass $sanitize and output an HTML element verbatim, not escaped. including any potentially unsafe scripts.
3. `ng-bind` - will output sanitized, escaped HTML.  `<div>Raw HTML</div>` will output `&lt;div&gt;Raw HTML&lt;/div&gt;`.  The browser will render `<div>Raw HTML</div>`

Based on your request, #3 would be most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Create a directive to display the nested HTML as text:
http://jsfiddle.net/6j0wqnvf/1/

```
module.directive('renderNestedHtml', function() {
    return {
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            var rawHtml = element[0].innerHTML;
            var code = angular.element('<pre></pre>');

            code.text(rawHtml.trim());
            element.replaceWith(code);
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: i like this solution... for long strings of html, this enabled me to write the strings in the template file

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `$sanitize`.

Either this way:

```
function MyCtrl ( $scope, $sanitize ) {
    $scope.rawHtml = "<div><script></script></div>";
    $scope.sanitizedHmtl = $sanitize( $scope.rawHtml );
}
```

or

```
<div ng-bind-html="rawHtml"></div>
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="sanitizedHtml"></div>
```

In a directive, insert the sanitized HTML:

```
element.html( scope.sanitizedHtml );
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514299/4015623) for more info - it's where I got this info from.

Comment: That's not what the question is asking. He doesn't want to insert DOM. He wants to insert text.