# AngularJS - use <pre> or encode HTML for code examples

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I laying out a styleguide with code examples within an AngularJS app.

In the past, I've used `<pre>`.  This no longer seems to work.  I've tried it in codepen, and it still parses the HTML.

```
I do not want this.
```

```
<h1>I DO want this.</h1>
```

I'm guessing there's a filter to encode or decode the HTML, but I don't know which way I need to go.  My intuition tells me I need to encode. However, everytime I try to google search a solution I get the opposite answers of what I want.

So for anyone who's better at googling than I am or know how to do this, please help.

**Edit** To appease the would be SO demigods, where's the code I ended up with...

This is how I started:

```
<xmp><button>Some example Button</button></xmp>
```

`<xmp>` is deprecated, and has line break/whitespace issues.  Couldn't use it.

Next one...

```
<pre><button>Some example Button</button></pre>
```

This sucked too, because it still parses the child nodes, meaning would get a button instead of a string.

What I ended up with:

```
// Template

    <div class="sgForms__ex">
        <div ng-bind-html="sgTrustHtml(buttons)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sgForms__code">
        <div ng-bind="buttons"></div>
    </div>

// Controller

angular.module('StyleGuide')
  .controller('StyleGuideFormsController', ['$scope', '$sce', 'ListHelper',
  function ($scope, $sce, listHelper) {

    $scope.sgTrustHtml = function (i) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(i);
    };

    $scope.buttons = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Call to Action</button>' +
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Secondary CTA</button>'+
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Inactive</button>';


}]);
```

I'm still running into an issue with line breaks. Note sure how I'm going to work around that.

Comment: did you tried `ng-bind-html` directive?

Comment: @PankajParkar so store the HTML to a $scope and then pop it in? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14514299/1202630

Comment: You have to show your code, where's there a scope value being set? Text is typically HTML-escaped by default, so it's hard to tell what you're doing.

Comment: `<pre>` never behaved the way you describe. `<xmp>` does.

Comment: @DanielBeck `<xmp>` is deprecated. There's also line breaking and whitespace issues. with it.

Comment: Hm, I honestly hadn't realized it was deprecated (not something I've needed to use, much).  OK, I got nothin, sorry.

Comment: I think this gets be where I want. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize  I was hoping to avoid putting the code example content into the controller, but oh well.

Comment: Wait a minute, doesn't ng-bind do what you want by default? http://jsfiddle.net/8eyq7rs7/    `$sanitize` is for when you want to parse html in data (`ng-bind-html`), but if you just ng-bind or {{}} it it'll come out unparsed...

Comment: Yeah, apparently.  Like I said, in my searching, the only answers I came up with were for the opposite of what I wanted to do.  `ng-bind` was what I wanted.  BUT, what I also need are some line breaks in the code exampes, which I don't know how to pass through the being without it spitting out the line-break with the rest of the contents.

Comment: @Plummer Show your code already! As I've said, from your explanation, it should be working. If I set `$scope.some = "<p>Hello</p>"`, you will see angled brackets on the screen

Comment: So... we're back to `<pre>`? http://jsfiddle.net/8eyq7rs7/2/   Gotta admit at this point I'm pretty confused about what it is you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem with the code you've shown is that you are using  `buttons` but the scope only has `examples`. The following snippet shows the HTML parsed, and unparsed.

To display newlines where you are displaying the code, just wrap it with a `pre` (or use CSS [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space))

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myDirective', ['$sce',function($sce) {}])
  .controller('StyleGuideFormsController', ['$scope', '$sce',
    function($scope, $sce) {
      $scope.sgTrustHtml = function(htmlString) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlString);
      };

      $scope.examples = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Call to Action</button>\n' +
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Secondary CTA</button>\n' +
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Inactive</button>';
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="StyleGuideFormsController">
    <pre><div ng-bind="examples"></div><pre>
    <div ng-bind-html="sgTrustHtml(examples)"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @DanielBeck Fixed it

Comment: the `examples` bit was a typo from carrying over to the answer.  In my code, using `ng-bind` works, but I don't know how to persist lines breaks.

Comment: @Plummer The focus of your question was displaying the code instead of interpreting the code. If you put a pre around the HTML that displays your code, then newlines will be treated as new lines instead of collapsed into whitespace like HTML usually does.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a function strip_tags to clean up your code.

```
angular.module('filters', []).factory('truncate', function () {
    return function strip_tags(input, allowed) {
      allowed = (((allowed || '') + '')
        .toLowerCase()
        .match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || [])
        .join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
      var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
        commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
      return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '')
        .replace(tags, function($0, $1) {
          return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
        });
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['filters'])
.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'truncate', function($scope, truncate){

  $('#myDivPre').replaceWith((truncate($('#myDiv'), '<a><br>')));

}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDivPre"></div>
```

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of what the OP wants, they don't want to strip, they want to maintain the tags.

Comment: @JuanMendes: And I love the downvotes fairies paying me a visit because they don't understand the question.

Comment: @Plummer One of the downvotes was mine (for the question, not this answer since Jean just misunderstood the question), I kind of understood it. However, in my book, a question without code is always worth a downvote, you did not explain well what you are currently doing.

Comment: @JuanMendes my bad, dude.  I was using `<pre>` which doesn't work.  The example I gave are essentially what SO does already, which is what I posted.  If you inspect SO, they use `<pre>`, but I'm sure they have some JS driving it.