# AngularJS: Escape HTML in input fields

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

What is the best way to escape HTML in the input field? For example, I've search input field

```
<input id="search" type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="search...">
```

And I want to escape if somebody types something like this:

```
<script>alert("test123");</script>
```

Comment: @Fran the question is clear. He wants to escape HTML characters.

Comment: @lin This Question does not show research effort and the requirements are not clear **to me** when OP wants to escape the characters. Hence I'm asking for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this completely depends on your use case. If you just want it to escape it for the users view (so basically sanitizing) you can use angular $sanitize & $sce for it

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

however if you want to store it somewhere and want it escaped, you can build a filter. You can find an example here: [Escape HTML text in an AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462612/escape-html-text-in-an-angularjs-directive)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#escape)  `_.escape([string=''])`. This is a easy and simple solution.

```
_.escape($scope.search);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `pattern` for your input box like -

```
<input type='text' pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9]+'>
```

Use an expression that best suits your needs.