# Why html escape /?

Tags: html, escaping

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12034334/1955298) (copied below)

What I didn't understand is why is / escaped?

---

There is also the solution from mustache.js

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js#L82

```
 var entityMap = {
    "&": "&amp;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#39;',
    "/": '&#x2F;'
  };

  function escapeHtml(string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {
      return entityMap[s];
    });
  }
```

Comment: because your delimeter is `/`

Comment: @NickFury The HTML isn't being put *in* the regex, so I don't see why that would be the case.

Comment: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/pull/199 (OWASP, in turn, has some nonsense about how it "helps to end an HTML entity".)  As always, the answer to your "why" question is "because it seemed like a good idea to someone when they wrote the code".

Comment: @Wooble - Have you got a link to the OWASP recommendation?

Comment: @Alohci: it certainly took you longer to type that comment and wait for a response than it would have taken to Google it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need at all to escape the / in HTML.

Comment: -1; doesn't answer OP's question, which is why at least 2 sources do recommend it.