# JQuery - output object as text?

Tags: jquery, html, output

So, I've got a widget that is looking to output live HTML source as text, as part of a review process. Is there a way that I can take a selected element, append it to a target div, and have it output as text instead of as a child in the DOM?

**UPDATE**: I'd like to avoid textareas if possible - they present a complication in my form setup, as well as a vulnerability for anyone with basic skill in firebug/inspectEl.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/NZFrQ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the html characters, so < becomes &lt; etc. - see answers here: [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You could insert the code into a textarea tag and the html will be printed as text

```
 jQuery('#idOfTextArea').text(html);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I apologize, I should have clarified - avoiding textareas would be best, as it complicates other parts of my app.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid `textarea` then the only other possible option I know is of `<code>` tag and `<pre>` tag will recognize white spaces so that code is properly indented. Try this fiddle.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NZFrQ/1/)**