# HTML: stop rendering HTML code inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If i write something like below inside textarea

```
<strong>test</strong>
```

inside textarea and then display it inside a div. It shows the text in bold letter instead of showing the html code as it is. So how can i avoid rendering html code. I just want to show as it is the text was entered by user.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WPQLP/1/  I can't replicate your error.

Comment: @Madthew — Since your attempt to replicate it doesn't include a textarea or a div and doesn't do anything to place what is typed in said textarea into said div, that isn't surprising.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WPQLP/2/ so it should work now. Forgot to update dhe jsfiddle.

Comment: @Madthew — The question says "I just want to show as it is the text was entered by user" and "display it inside a div" — Your example hard codes the data into the textarea (so not entered by the user) and doesn't display it in a div at all.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown us any code, but since you have tagged this `jQuery` I'll assume you have something like:

```
$('div').html(
     $('textarea').val()
);
```

Use the `text` method instead, so what the user has typed is treated as text instead of HTML.

```
$('div').text(
     $('textarea').val()
);
```

See [a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/WPQLP/4/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `<` and `>` characters to their HTML entities.

```
&lt;strong&gt;test&lt;/strong&gt;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Cbj7/1/)

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to escape the html formatting

this should work

```
var someHtmlString = "<strong>test</strong>";
var escaped = $("div.someClass").text(someHtmlString).html();
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25207/103959)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<pre>` tag so that it shows the user input as is. This preserves all formatting such as spaces and newlines

```
<textarea  rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<div>
   <pre id="output">
   </pre>
</div>
```

js

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
$('#output').text($(this).val()); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WPQLP/5/

Answer (score 0):

`&lt;strong&gt;test&lt;/strong&gt;` produces `<strong>test</strong>`

These are called HTML entities and behave like that because normally `<foo>` means a HTML tag, and it's supposed to be rendered. [Read more about HTML entities on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)