# show HTML as plain text

Tags: html, plaintext

im looking for a way to show html as html without the browser reading it,
i found `<plainttext>` but once i start it i can't stop it 
for example:

```
<plaintext>
    <span> dobeediedabiedadadee olleeeeee</span>
</plaintext>
<h1>hi</h1>
```

in this example the span had to be shown as text and the h1 as a header, but the output is:

```
    <span> dobeediedabiedadadee olleeeeee</span>
</plaintext>
<h1>hi</h1>

</body>


</html>
```

here a JSFiddle link:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkhj5/)

a other solution as plaintext is also welcome
thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

`plaintext` [**has long been deprecated**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/plaintext), just use `&gt;` and `&lt;`

```
&lt;span&gt; dobeediedabiedadadee olleeeeee&lt;/span&gt;
```

DEMO: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkhj5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could always use [javascript to escape the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery). [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VEXkk/).

```
html.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link describes the difficulty in using `<plaintext>`. long story short it is not fully supported in any browser and you should be using `<pre>` instead.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/plaintext

Answer (score 0):

`<plaintext>` is not a pair tag. From that tag to the rest of the page, everything is interpreted as text. However, this is not standard and obsolette in HTML5:

> **Examples**
>   No, really. don't use it.

It is literally written in the [w3 reference](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/plaintext)

Answer (score 0):

it is compatibility issue some browser completely ignores coding of

have a look at this link http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/plaintext

i would suggest you use  instead

Answer (score 0):

Use PRE

```
<pre>
    <span> dobeediedabiedadadee olleeeeee</span>
</pre>
<h1>hi</h1>
```