# Escaping all symbols in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

Is there a simple way to escape **All** symbols in HTML?

I took into account ways such as:
[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)
or [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery) and related, but only five symbols are escaped. I could list all symbols and their entities, but I would like not to.

If my browser can so easily change `&copy;` into `©` why can't I do it easily the other way around?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? And what do you mean by “all symbols”? If you escape all characters in an HTML document, it isn’t an HTML document any more.

Comment: By "all symbols" you mean "all symbols for which a [named character entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) is defined"? And why would you want to do that - it's not necessary to escape these?