# What is replaceAll performance secret? [HTML escape]

Tags: javascript, performance

I spent some time looking best way to escape html string and found some discussions on that: [discussion 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery) [discussion 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding). It leads me to [replaceAll](http://dumpsite.com/forum/index.php?topic=4.msg29#msg29) function. Then I did performance tests and tried to find solution achieving similar speed with no success :(

Here is my final [test case set](http://jsperf.com/htmlencoderegex/30). I found it on net and expand with my tries (4 cases at bottom) and still can not reach `replaceAll()` performance.

What is secret witch makes `replaceAll()` solution so speedy?

Greets!

Code snippets:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(str1, str2, ignore) 
{
   return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(/([\/\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g,"\\$&"),(ignore?"gi":"g")),(typeof(str2)=="string")?str2.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$"):str2);
};
```

credits for [qwerty](http://dumpsite.com/forum/index.php?topic=4.msg29#msg29)

Fastest case so far:

```
html.replaceAll('&', '&amp;').replaceAll('"', '&quot;').replaceAll("'", '&#39;').replaceAll('<', '&lt;').replaceAll('>', '&gt;');
```

Comment: Many built in methods are implemented in native code and pre-optimized (regexes being one), emulating them in Javascript in a speedier way is just plain hard to do.

Comment: sure, but why "replace new RegExp" case is so slow. It uses RegExp too.

Comment: still replace without regex seems to be faster http://jsperf.com/replaceallvssplitjoin

Comment: @Mr_Green The multiple replace is wrong, because it only replaces the first occurrence :)

Comment: confirm. here is proper compare: http://jsperf.com/replaceallvssplitjoin/2

Comment: @Jack yup :) realized now.

Comment: Always compile your regexes; http://jsperf.com/htmlencoderegex/32

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It seems `compile` method is deprecated. [**link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features)

Comment: @Mr_Green I sure still see a performance difference using it, I'm guessing that difference will disappear soon then when the browsers are optimised accordingly.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it seems to be the trick. replaceAll definition somehow forces browsers to compile included regexps...
very tricky :/

Comment: Found it. Look answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i found it!
Thanks [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack) for pointing me on jsperf specific

> I should note that the test results are strange; when .replaceAll() is
>   defined inside Benchmark.prototype.setup it runs twice as fast
>   compared to when it's defined globally (i.e. inside a  tag).
>   I'm still not sure why that is, but it definitely must be related to
>   how jsperf itself works.

The answer is:

`replaceAll` - this reach jsperf limit/bug, caused by special sequence `"\\$&"`, so results was wrong.

`compile()` - when called with no argument it changes regexp definition to `/(?:)`. I dont know if it is bug or something, but performance result was crappy after it was called.

Here is my [result safe tests](http://jsperf.com/htmlencoderegex/34).

Finally I prepared [proper test cases](http://jsperf.com/htmlencoderegex/35).

The result is, that for HTML escape best way it to use native DOM based solution, like:

```
document.createElement('div').appendChild(document.createTextNode(html)).parentNode.innerHTML
```

or if you repeat it many times you can do it with once prepared variables:

```
//prepare variables
var DOMtext = document.createTextNode("test");
var DOMnative = document.createElement("span");
DOMnative.appendChild(DOMtext);

//main work for each case
function HTMLescape(html){
  DOMtext.nodeValue = html;
  return DOMnative.innerHTML
}
```

Thank you all for collaboration & posting comments and directions.

***jsperf bug description***

The `String.prototype.replaceAll` was defined as followed:

```
function (str1, str2, ignore) {
  return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(repAll, "\\#{setup}"), (ignore ? "gi" : "g")), (typeof(str2) == "string") ? str2.replace(/\$/g, "$$") : str2);
}
```

Comment: Could you link to the jsperf bug?

Comment: @Jack when you start any buggy test (where replaceAll is defined in setup() procedure) go to console and display body of `String.prototype.replaceAll`. I'll do some comment to answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

As far as performance goes, I find that the below function is as good as it gets:

```
String.prototype.htmlEscape = function() {
    var amp_re = /&/g, sq_re = /'/g, quot_re = /"/g, lt_re = /</g, gt_re = />/g;

    return function() {
        return this
          .replace(amp_re, '&amp;')
          .replace(sq_re, '&#39;')
          .replace(quot_re, '&quot;')
          .replace(lt_re, '&lt;')
          .replace(gt_re, '&gt;');
    }
}();
```

It initializes the regular expressions and returns a closure that actually performs the replacement.

[**Performance test**](http://jsperf.com/html-escaper-v2)

I should note that the test results are strange; when `.replaceAll()` is defined *inside* `Benchmark.prototype.setup` it runs twice as fast compared to when it's defined globally (i.e. inside a `<script>` tag). I'm still not sure why that is, but it definitely must be related to how jsperf itself works.

<strike>**Using `RegExp.compile()`**</strike>

I wanted to avoid using a deprecated function, mostly because this kind of performance should be done automatically by modern browsers. Here's a version with compiled expressions:

```
String.prototype.htmlEscape2 = function() {
    var amp_re = /&/g, sq_re = /'/g, quot_re = /"/g, lt_re = /</g, gt_re = />/g;

    if (RegExp.prototype.compile) {
        amp_re.compile();
        sq_re.compile();
        quot_re.compile();
        lt_re.compile();
        gt_re.compile();
    }

    return function() {
        return this
          .replace(amp_re, '&amp;')
          .replace(sq_re, '&#39;')
          .replace(quot_re, '&quot;')
          .replace(lt_re, '&lt;')
          .replace(gt_re, '&gt;');
    }
}
```

Doing so blows everything else out of the water!

[**Performance test**](http://jsperf.com/html-escaper-v2/3)

The reason why `.compile()` gives such a performance boost is because when you compile a global expression, e.g. `/a/g` it gets converted to `/(?:)/` (on Chrome), which renders it useless.

If compilation can't be done, a browser should throw an error instead of silently destroying it.

Comment: Look at @Joachim Isaksson comment above. I think he found the trick.

Comment: @Saram I didn't test with the deprecated `.compile()`, but I doubt that would be a useful statistic. Something in the test benchmark is influencing the results.

Comment: @Saram Also, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), literal regular expressions *are* compiled.

Comment: @Saram I've updated the code with a compiled version; I still feel browsers should optimize for this stuff.

Comment: I fount that `compile()` destroys regexp, so it can not be used. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there are faster ways to do this.

If you could do an inline split and join, you will get a better performance.

```
//example below
var test = "This is a test string";
var test2 = test.split("a").join("A");
```

Try this and run the performance test.

Comment: Using the replaceAll function : **0.054** seconds/
Using the replaceAll2 function : **0.106** seconds/
Inline Split/Join : **0.111** seconds/
Inline RegExp Object : **0.182** seconds
Inline RegExp Object without string: **0.134** seconds