# template function using a spread operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel here, just playing around with a question that was put to me. How would I write a simple template engine function. My immediate answer was more old school but with ES6 and the new spread operator, got me thinking maybe there is a better way of doing this now using the spread operator. 
Anyone got any ides ? Or would I still have to loop through and find my delimiter like i was using below const delimiter =  '{{ name }}';.

```
    const root = document.getElementById('root');
    const html = "<p>My name is {{ name }}</p>";

    var template = function(html){
      return function(data){
        for(var prop in data){
          var regx = "{{\\s?" + prop + "\\s?}}";
          html = html.replace(new RegExp(regx, "ig"), data[prop]);  
        }
        return html;
        }
    }

    var tmp = template(html);
    root.innerHTML = tmp({
      name: "John Doe"
    });;
```

Comment: I don't see any operations here that mimic the spread operator.

Comment: What got you thinking about spread syntax? I can't see how it would be useful in a template engine.

Comment: Take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673860/defining-a-html-template-to-append-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673860/defining-a-html-template-to-append-using-jquery).

Comment: I haven't used the spread operator but what I have seen is it allows you to be able to pass objects around using string templates ${string} I just thought I might be able to use it instead of looping through my string to find a delimiter but I guess not after reading more about the spread operator.  I guess the only way is to loop through like I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not with the spread operator, but I would use `class` instead of the function function, and `Object.keys` to generate one regular expression (for all keys), using the callback argument of `replace`:

```js
class Template {
    constructor(html) {
        this.html = html;
    }
    resolve(data) {
        const regx = "{{\\s?(" + Object.keys(data).join('|') + ")\\s?}}";
        return this.html.replace(new RegExp(regx, "ig"), (m, prop) => data[prop])
    }
}

const delimiter = '{{ name }}',
    root = document.getElementById('root'),
    html = "<p>My name is {{ name }}</p>",
    tmp = new Template(html);

root.innerHTML = tmp.resolve({
    name: "John Doe"
});
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Note that you should probably make sure that any special characters in the properties [are escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) so they don't get interpreted by `new RegExp`. But as you did not do this in your solution, I left that out as well.