# Enhance parts of multi page application with react or vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, vue.js

I'm developing a enterprise application with `java` & `hibernate` & `spring mvc` in the server side and using `jquery` in the client side (not a SPA).

Now in the search page i use ajax and get only `json` response, but i don't want to write something like this below in every search or pagination request.

```
function(ajaxData) {
    ....
    $('#search').html('' +
        '<div class="search-container">' + 
          '<div class="search-item">' +
             '<div class="title-item">'+ajaxData.title+'</div>' + 
             ...
             ...
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>'
    )
    ....
}
```

I think it's easy to use `jsx` with a `react` or `vue` *component* just in this page to refresh the results.

I want also reuse some html blocks  and i think it will be easy with `react` or `vue`

I used to build a little **SPA** project and it's all about `npm` and `webpack` and bundling, but i really don't want to use them since i have a **multi page application** and it's very suitable for my project.

I think the same thing `facebook` is doing, they use react but `facebook` is not a SPA.

**How can i achieve this hybrid approach ?**

Comment: It's hard to use react without JSX. And using JSX requires webpack. If you don't wanna use webpack, it seems like Vue is an easier option for you

Comment: To do a simple ajax request, jQuery seems like a good options. You already have it apparently, just use that. $.ajax(). See docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: you can find production ready vuejs files on CDN, just  a script tag and start you code in mvvm. anglar1.x also works but suggest vue. react also can run without compile but only for practice

Comment: You might not need React/Vue, have you looked at fetch? it's a very simple way to implement AJAX requests https://davidwalsh.name/fetch

Comment: @Pixelomo it's not about ajax, i update my question

Comment: @Youssef are you trying to achieve rendering only changed elements? or just a cleaner code for updating specific elements-value ?

Comment: @NiritLevi i think i need both, rendering only changed elements with cleaner code than using jquery

Comment: @Youssef if you don't need stateful components, react/vue/angular may be over kill. Since you already have jQuery on the page, have you considered using [jQuery templates](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had done a similar kind of stuff in the past. I injected a small react component into the DOM.

Here is how I did it:

Create a React component in JSX, let's call it `Demo`:

```
export class Demo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>This is a dummy component.</h1>
    }
}
```

Now use the [renderToStaticMarkup](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) function to get the static html.

```
const staticMarkup = renderToStaticMarkup(<Demo PASS_YOUR_PROPS/>);
```

You have the HTML, now you can insert this markup at the desired location using the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Apologies if I misunderstood your question.

#### UPDATE

We could also use the `render()` for this purpose. Example:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = () => {
  render(
    <Demo PASS_YOUR_PROPS/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
};
```

Working solution with render() and renderToStaticMarkup: https://codesandbox.io/s/w061xx0n38

#### render()

> Render a ReactElement into the DOM in the supplied container and
> return a reference to the component.
>
> If the ReactElement was previously rendered into the container, this
> will perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to
> reflect the latest React component.

#### renderToStaticMarkup()

> This doesn't create extra DOM attributes such as data-react-id, that
> React uses internally. This is useful if you want to use React as a
> simple static page generator, as stripping away the extra attributes
> can save lots of bytes.

Comment: `renderToStaticMarkup` it's not just used with `ReactDOMServer` on a node server only ? specially with server side rendering SSR .... i'm using `spring-mvc` and i want to achieve that in the client side not in the server

Comment: It's usage is not restricted to the server. I have used on the client side.

Comment: As per the snippet, you added, this will fit perfectly in the picture. Create a React component for your HTML elements/JSX and pass the data returned on success as the prop.

Comment: why not using directly `render()` of `ReactDOM` package ?

Comment: @Youssef I have created an example that shows how to achieve this using the render() and the renderToStaticMarkup() method. Please have a look. https://codesandbox.io/s/w061xx0n38. 
I had never used the render() for this purpose earlier, but since you mentioned it, I tried the render method. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have an existing multi page application **without** a build step (that is, without webpack/babel), I believe one very simple way of achieving what you want is using Vue.js.

You can define a template and update only the data.

Here's a demo of how you would do the code you showed in the question:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ajaxDataAvailable: false,
    ajaxData: {
      title: '',
      results: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchUsers() {
      this.ajaxDataAvailable = false; // hide user list
      $.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", (data) => {
        this.ajaxData.title = 'These are our Users at ' + new Date().toISOString();
        this.ajaxData.results = data;
       this.ajaxDataAvailable = true; // allow users to be displayed
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
/* CSS just for demo, does not affect functionality could be existing CSS */
.search-container { border: 2px solid black; padding: 5px; }
.title-item { background: gray; font-weight: bold; font-size: x-large; }
.result-item { border: 1px solid gray; padding: 3px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="fetchUsers">Click to fetch the Users</button><br><br>

  <div class="search-container" v-if="ajaxDataAvailable">
    <div class="search-item">
      <div class="title-item"> {{ ajaxData.title }}</div>
      <div class="result-item" v-for="result in ajaxData.results">
        Name: {{ result.name }} - Phone: {{ result.phone }} - Edit name: <input v-model="result.name">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

In this example, we have:

- A method `fetchUsers` that will perform the ajax call;
- The `fetchUsers` method is bound to the `click` event of the `<button>` via `@click="methodName"` (which is a shorthand to `v-on:click="methodName"`).
- A `v-if` (`v-if="ajaxDataAvailable"`) that makes the `.search-container` div hidden until the `ajaxDataAvailable` property is `true`.
- The rendering of some data in the template using interpolation: `{{ ajaxData.title }}`, note that this picks the value from the objects declared in the `data:` part of the Vue instance (the `new Vue({...` code) below and is **automatically** updated whenever `ajaxData.title` changes (what happens inside the `fetchUsers` method when the Ajax call completes.
- The rendering of a list using `v-for`: `v-for="result in ajaxData.results"`. This iterates in the `ajaxData.results` array, that is too updated inside the `fetchUsers` method.
- The use of an `<input>` element with the `v-model` directive, which allows us to edit the `result.name` value directly (which also updates the template automatically).

There's much more to Vue, this is just an example. If needed, more elaborated demos can be made.

As far as **integrating into an existing application**, you could paste this very code into any HTML page and it would be already working, no need for webpack/babel whatsoever.

Comment: in react doc `React is unaware of changes made to the DOM outside of React. It determines updates based on its own internal representation, and if the same DOM nodes are manipulated by another library, React gets confused and has no way to recover.` is this the same case for `vuejs` ?

Comment: Yes, although you can remedy it a bit if you know what nodes will change specifically, in general, that applies to Vue as well. May I ask why is that a concern?

Comment: Ah, Vue doesn't "get confused and has no way to recover". In fact, if something else alters the DOM outside of Vue, if not handled manually by the programmer, it is simply overwritten by Vue in the next update cycle (which happens whenever some data of the Vue instance changes).

Answer (score 4):

So, there are two things you could do to re-use your code:

- I would recommend React for sharing code as components. This page from Official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) explains how to use react with jquery.
  Additional resources for integrating react and jquery [jquery-ui with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836553/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-react-js/40350880#40350880), [Using react and jquery together](http://tech.oyster.com/using-react-and-jquery-together/), [react-training](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md)
- Or, use some template engine so you do not need to go through the trouble of integrating a new library and making it work alongside jquery. This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673860/defining-a-html-template-to-append-using-jquery) provides lot of options for doing this.

Unless your planning on migrating your jquery app to react in the long run, I would not recommend using react just for one page. It would be easier to go with the template engine route.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of the requirement, you just need:

1. Dynamic, data driven HTML blocks
2. Which need to be reusable

In this case, since we don't need state, having an entire framework like react/vue/angular may be overkill.

My recommendation would be to go for a templating engine like [jQuery Templates Plugin](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template) or [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

You can even store the HTML blocks as separate reusable modules which you can invoke as needed across your pages.

Sample using Handlebars:

```js
var tmpl = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("comment-template").innerHTML);

function simulatedAjax(cb){
  setTimeout(function(){
    cb(null, {title:'First Comment', body: 'This is the first comment. Be sure to add yours too'});
  },2000);
}


simulatedAjax(function(err, data){
  if(err){
    // Handle error
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = tmpl(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<div id="target">
Loading...
</div>

<script id="comment-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="comment">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

NOTE:

One disadvantage of using this approach (as opposed to a framework like react/vue/angular) is that you will need to handle event binding and unbinding manually. You can mitigate this to some extent by wrapping your templates in a function which mounts and unmounts it automatically.

```js
// Single reuable JS file for each component
(function(namespace) {
  var _tmpl = Handlebars.compile('<div class="comment"><h1>{{title}}</h1><p>{{body}}</p></div>');

  function titleClickHandler(ev) {
    alert(ev.target.innerHTML)
  }

  function CommentWidget(target, data) {
    var self = this;
    self.data = data;
    self.target = document.querySelector(target);
  }
  CommentWidget.prototype.render = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.target.innerHTML = _tmpl(self.data);

    // Register Event Listeners here
    self.target.querySelector('h1').addEventListener('click', titleClickHandler)

  }
  CommentWidget.prototype.unmount = function() {
    var self = this;
    // Unregister Event Listeners here
    self.target.querySelector('h1').removeEventListener('click', titleClickHandler);

    self.target.innerHTML = '';

  }

  window._widgets.CommentWidget = CommentWidget;

})(window._widgets = window._widgets || {})


// Usage on your page 
var w = new _widgets.CommentWidget('#target', {
  title: 'Comment title',
  body: 'Comment body is remarkably unimaginative'
});

// Render the widget and automatically bind listeners
w.render();

// Unmount and perform clean up at a later time if needed 
//w.unmount();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>
```