# Add class/text to a jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to clone the following HTML template and add class/text to it.

```html
<template id="result">
    <section>
        <div class="alert">
            <p class="someText"></p>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

So the user first submits a question:

```html
<div id="answer"></div>

<section class="row">
    <form id="form" action="/" method="GET">
        <div>
            <input id="question" />
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Then the script executes:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            data: {...},
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/result'
        }).done(myFunction);
    });
});
```

And finally it clones the template (ID `#result`), add a class to the element containing a class `alert` and add some text to the element containing a class `someText`, and appends it to the element containing ID `#answer`.

```js
function myFunction(result) {
    clone = $('#result').clone();
    $('.alert', clone).addClass('myClass');
    $('.someText', clone).text('myText');
    clone.appendTo("#answer");
}
```

The function executes (I added a `console.log()` to the end of it to be sure) but nothing is appending.

Comment: I do not see where you clone the template. Also you would end up with multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: Well I do not use ```.clone()``` but I store my template in ```elt``` then copy it in ```clone```.

Comment: I see now that you are replicating the `<template>` element. If you inspect the answer, I bet it is appending, yet not being rendered. Also, id will clone the ID, so now you have two or more elements with the same ID. I would advise cloning the children.

Comment: Are you doing anything from stopping your form from being submitted and reloading your page, wiping out all changes in the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
function create_message(result) {
  var section = $("#result").children().clone();
  $('.alert', section).addClass(result.status);
  $('.address', section).text(result.address);
  $('.extract', section).text(result.extract);
  $('.question', section).text(result.question);
  section.appendTo("#answer");
}
```

This creates a clone of all the HTML Elements inside the Template with ID result. It then finds specific classes inside the Object `section` and makes changes.

You can also do the following.

```
section.find(".alert").addClass(result.status);
```

See more: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

**Update**

> Use `<template>` to hold some content that will be hidden...

So if you Clone the Template and append it, it will still be hidden.

Try the following:

```
function myFunction(result) {
  clone = $('#result > section').clone();
  $('.alert', clone).addClass('myClass');
  $('.someText', clone).text('myText');
  clone.appendTo("#answer");
}
```

**Update 2**

I don't use `<template>`, so I had to re-read some stuff. It has a `content` portion, so it has an HTML Fragment contained within and is not like other HTML Elements, more like an iFrame. So we need to collect the content versus cloning it.

See: [How to use HTML template tag with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768534/how-to-use-html-template-tag-with-jquery)

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rpd9h0mf/20/

Your code will be something more like the following.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function showResults(results) {
    var clone = $($('#result').html());
    $('.alert', clone).addClass(results.class);
    $('.someText', clone).text(results.answer);
    clone.appendTo("#answer");
  }

  $('#question-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      data: {
        q: $("#question").val()
      },
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/result',
      success: showResults
    });
  });
});
```

This creates a new jQuery Object based on the HTML Content of the Template. Now you can properly edit it and append it.

Comment: With this code, ```section``` does not even append to ```answer```, I don't understand why...

Comment: Are you sure `#answer` exists at the time the code runs? To confirm, you can use: `console.log($('#answer').length);`. This should output a `length` of 1.

Comment: Yes, ```answer``` is in the ```body``` but nothing is happening.

Comment: @fr0zie where is this function, `create_message()` get executed?

Comment: ```$(document).ready(function () {$('#form').on('submit', function (event) {$.ajax({data: {...}, type: 'GET', url: '/result'}).done(create_message);});});```

Comment: @fr0zie please check your Console and Network section and confirm that a Request is not failing. If `<section>` is not appearing, it sounds like the function is not running.So maybe your AJAX is not calling it.

Comment: The function is running, I'm doing a ```console.log()``` at the end of it and when I submit the form, the console prints ```1```.

Comment: @fr0zie please go back and provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty I modified my question to be as clear as possible.

Comment: Still nothing appending in the ```answer``` div after your update... It's a mystery.

Comment: @fr0zie please check your console and inspect the `answer` element to see if new items are being appended, yet not being shown. Maybe there is CSS that is preventing them from being seen. I also do not see where you prevent the Form from completing it's default action. ensure to include `event.preventDefault()` first.

Comment: @fr0zie when you get the Results, are they a single Object or an Array of Objects? Please provide an example of the results in your post.

Comment: @fr0zie see Update 2, I found the issue that was tripping us both up.

Comment: @Twisty Working perfectly! Thanks for the help.