# Invalid Json when serializing entity using JMSSerializer with fields content HTML tags

Tags: json, symfony, ckeditor, jmsserializerbundle

I installed the `JMSSerializerbundle` with symfony2 to get JSON response of my Doctrine Entities.

The problem is that when I have a string field created by ckeditor and content `HTML` tags I got an invalid JSON response.

```
    "courses": [
    {
        "requests": [

        ],
        "id": 38,
        "course_content": "
            pmlllo<\/p>",
        "course_title": "hhjhhhh",
        "course_type": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Dershane Dersi",
            "courses": [

            ]
        },
        "description": "

             ppoookokokok<\/p>"
    }
 ]
```

Using http://jsonlint.com/ I got this error

Parse error on line 154:...
"course_content": "pmlllo</p>",
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got to encode HTML if you want to store it in JSON. On the server-side (PHP), [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) should do the trick. For the client side, please refer to this question: [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery).