# why css is not applied in variable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can you please tell me why my css is applied in my variable.
when I write like this

```
 html+='<div>'+tenLengthString+'</div>';
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/5/
 it show my contend in row.but I need to show timestamp in all row.At every row I need to show timestamp.So I change my variable .

```
 html+='<div style=width:60%; float:left;><b>'+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" +  seconds+'</b></div><div style=width:40%; float:left; text-align:right; ><b>'+ 1 +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div></div><div>'+tenLengthString+'</div>';
```

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/6/

but it look different .how can i display timestamp in front of each row ?

```
var words = str.split(" ");
var tenLengthString = "";
var html='';
for(var index = 0; index < words.length; index++)
{
    var currentWord = words[index];
    var currentLength = tenLengthString.length;    
    if(((currentLength + currentWord.length + ((currentLength > 0) ? 1: 0))) > 30)
    {        
        html+='<div style=width:60%; float:left;><b>'+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" +  seconds+'</b></div><div style=width:40%; float:left; text-align:right; ><b>'+ 1 +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div></div><div>'+tenLengthString+'</div>';
        console.log(tenLengthString);        
        tenLengthString = currentWord;        
    } else {
        if(currentLength > 0)
            tenLengthString += " ";    
        tenLengthString += currentWord;
    }    
    if(index == words.length - 1){
      console.log(tenLengthString);
       html+='<div>'+tenLengthString+'</div>';

    }        
}
$("#test").html(html)
```

Comment: Any reason for not using a list?

Comment: You should be very careful when concatenating data and html. For example what if `tenLengthString` contains html tags?

Comment: in demo i use static data but in real example I have streaming live.I think the best way to take div

Comment: @zord how i can detect br tag in my string data ?

Comment: No, it wont be better to use div.

Comment: You dont need to detect the html. You could use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Comment: I agree with @Avempace. You don't want to detect html, you want to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enclose style in double quotes :`style=""`
2. inner 'line-item level div's should be inline-block
3. containing 'row level' div need opening  tag
4. lose the float styles
5. Adjust styles to clean up the row.
6. Consider using CSS to style the div's you are concatenating `<div class="">`

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it a bit by separating the css. I also would prefer to create a list than so many divs.

```
html+='<li><span class="timestamp">'+ hours + ":" + minutes + 
   ":" +  seconds+'</span><span class="number">'+ 1 +
   '</span>'+tenLengthString+'</li>';
```

The css could be(for example):

```
li {
    list-style: none;
}

.timestamp {
    width:20%; 
    float: left;    
    font-weight: bold;
}

.number {
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
    width:20%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/10/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the double quote on the style attributes.

```
 html+='<div style="width:60%; float:left;"><b>'+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" +  seconds+'</b></div><div style="width:40%; float:left; text-align:right;" ><b>'+ 1 +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div></div>
```

Sorry can't save on jsfiddle.