# Find and separate links in JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a Windows 8 app with HTML + JS and have a field where the user can input some data, when they revisit the page I set a `<div>` equal to their input. It is possible they may input a URL so I want to convert it to a link. Every example I has read about talks about enclosing it in an  tag however when I write the text into the div I use "div.innerText" rather than "div.innerHTML" in case the user wrote incorrect HTML as their data which then causes the app to crash.

Is there anyway I can fail safe against the user entering incorrect HTML and still have hyperlinks in the text?

Comment: Maybe look a RegExp (Regular Expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [escape user data first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery#12034334), then [replace URLs with links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links#21925491) and use innerHTML property to write data into the element

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the information I was looking for. I wasnt aware of "escaping user data"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to replace a URL to a link using `innerHTML`.

```
    // ... first write to element.innerText if you want to then:
    var url_regex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(url_regex, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```