# js_string with double quoted expression

Tags: javascript, json, escaping, freemarker

We have a FTL that has -

`<a href='javascript:func("${event.title}");'>Link</a>`

When the value has an apostrophe, like `Norman'S Birthday` - it breaks.

We used `js_string` to fix it -

`<a href="javascript:func('${event.title?js_string}');">Link</a>`

But we also had to change the double quotes around `$expression` to single quotes - this does Not work with double quotes.

**Question** -

Is there a way to fix this with the original double quotes around the `$expression` ?

Something like -

`<a href='javascript:func("${event.title?js_string}");'>Link</a>`

Note the above does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to support apostrophes in javascript when building up html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154267/what-is-the-correct-way-to-support-apostrophes-in-javascript-when-building-up-ht)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Not a duplicate, as OP needs to do this with FreeMarker.

Comment: Is there a way to tell FTL at entire file-level to take care of escaping? Like a global-macro?

Comment: @jforex78 You can configure FreeMarker to use HTML auto-escaping on all `*.ftlh` files, or even on all files. But I believe the material lined from my answer covers that. If you some complex case, like only templates inside certain directories should be auto-escaped, then see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_templateconfigurations.html.

Answer (score 2):

You need two kind of escaping applied here: JavaScript string escaping and HTML escaping. You need both, as the two formats are independent, and the JavaScript is embedded into HTML.

How to do that... the primitive way is `event.title?js_string?html`, but it's easy to forget to add that `?html`, so don't do that. Instead, use auto-escaping (see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html#dgui_quickstart_template_autoescaping). If you can't use that form of auto-escaping for some reason (like you are using some old FreeMarker version and aren't allowed to upgrade), put the whole template into `<#escape x as x?html>...</#escape>`. In both cases, you can just write `${event.title?js_string}`, and it will just work.

However, if you are using `#escape`, ensure that the `incompatible_improvements` setting (see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_incompatible_improvements.html) is at least 2.3.20, or else `?html` doesn't escape `'`.

Comment: Nice i will try that shortly and post.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the value of `event.title` so that single quotes are replaces with `&apos;` and double quotes are replaces with `&quot;`, then you won't have to worry at all about which kind of quotes you use for the rest of it.

Comment: Yes thats a good alternative. Except - we have to replace all special characters one by one - like `apos`, `quot`, etc. We need something like `js_string` that takes care of escaping in a general manner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`?js_string` should be outside curly brackets {}. Now you should use double quotes " " around href value, if you wanna handle single quotes ' ' inside the string and vice versa. Single and double quote can not be used in same string, so either of them needs to be replaced to other.

solution:
`<a href="javascript:func('${event.title!?js_string}');">Link</a>`

Same expression can be used in JavaScript to handle special characters