# Remove HTML tags and entites from string coming from server

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

In an app I receive some HTML text: since the app can't display (interpret) HTML, I need to remove any HTML tag and entity from the string I receive from the server.

I tried the following, but this one removes HTML tags but not entities (eg. &bnsp;):

```
stringFromServer.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Disclaimer: I need a pure JavaScript solution (no JQuery, Underscore, etc.).

[UPDATE] **I'm reading all your answers now and I forgot to mention that I'm using JavaScript BUT the environment is not a web page, so I have no DOM**.

Comment: __[Don't parse HTML using regexes!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)__ Use JavaScript's DOM api instead.

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Comment: So, you have no `innerText` / `textContent` etc? That's going to get ugly...

Comment: I updated the post, SORRY for not mentioning I can't use HTML but I can only manipulate it

Comment: This means you're going to have to write your own DOM parser. Which will be  a pain in the ass. There's no "single" regex out there that can reliably remove HTML tags.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I hate to have pain in my ass.

Comment: So, what environment are you using that doesn't support DOM?

Comment: @Cerbrus: It's a proprietary project, nothing "famous"  :-)

Comment: Written in...? Or is it a proprietary JavaScript interpreter, too?

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm on this project since yesterday, about anything is coded in C++ and (they say) the engine is the one used by Firefox

Comment: I see. It appears you might need to write (or use) a JS html parser. Try these: https://www.npmjs.org/package/htmlparser http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/ for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var placeholder = document.createElement('div');
placeholder.innerHTML = stringFromServer;

var theText = placeholder.innerText;
```

`.innerText` only grabs text content from the element.

However, since it appears you don't have access to any DOM manipulation at all, you're probably going to have to use some kind of HTML parser, like these:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/htmlparser
http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/

Comment: I would recommend this approach. Cleanest, straight forward, cross-browser, and seems to do the entities as well: http://jsfiddle.net/aca7h9g5/

Comment: I'm not using JavaScript in an HTML page

Comment: @3000: I included those html parser links in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without using regexes or phantom divs can be [found on Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML).

I put the code in a [JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pe13vayr/):

```
var sMyString = "<a id=\"a\"><b id=\"b\">hey!<\/b><\/a>";
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(sMyString, "text/xml");
// print the name of the root element or error message
alert(oDOM.documentElement.nodeName == "parsererror" ?
       "error while parsing" : oDOM.documentElement.textContent);
```

Comment: I have no DOM, so I can't use DOMParser (I edited the question, sorry for not mentioning it)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, parse the HTML snippet in a new document and do your dom manipulations from that (if you'd rather keep it separate from the current document):

```
var tmpDoc=document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
tmpDoc.body.innerHTML="<a href='#'>some text</a><p style=''> more text</p>";
tmpDoc.body.textContent;
```

`tmpDoc.body.textContent` evaluates to:

```
some text more text
```

Answer (score -1):

```
stringFromServer.replace(/(<([^>]+)>|&[^;]+;)/ig, "")
```

Comment: Maybe this is what I'm looking for, but could you explain the regex?

Comment: @3000: There's not a single regex that will not break on strings like `var myString = "This < that <span>thingy</span> & mind the ; <span>right?</span>"`

Comment: @Cerbrus: OP is getting html. "<" is encoded as &lt; in html. "&" and ";" are encoded also. Fun fact: ">" does not need to be escaped, but usually is. You are assuming, there is javascript in the html. Well, I guess than a regex would be impossible.

Comment: Eh, no. Strings sent from the server containing HTML tags are not encoded like that at all.

Comment: Web pages are strings sent from the server, you are looking at one right now. ;) But I know that you are talking about javascript strings. :)

Comment: Sure, technically, web pages are similar to strings sent from the server. But the actual data that's sent does not contain `&lt;` instead of `<`. It just contains the exact HTML as "built" or written on the server. The same is valid when you're sending a string containing HTML from the server, as data.

Comment: @Leif : no, I correctly receive the HTML tags, they're not escaped. But I receive entities (&apos; etc) and I can't remove them