# jQuery don't parse HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string which is essentially html elements, and I'm using jQuery to try to append this string to a div:

```
var content = '<div>Test</div>';
$('div').append(content);
```

Is there a way in JavaScript or jQuery to make it so it doesn't parse the string so in my div I get:

```
<div>Test</div>
```

instead of

```
Test
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `.text()` function to put strings into HTML elements. If you were to use the `.html()` function it would simply put `test`

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
var content = '<div>Test</div>';
$('div').text(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a smaller `div` and call `text`:

```
$('div').append($('<div>').text(content));
```

This might look cleaner with

```
$('<div>').text(content).appendTo('div');
```

Or, if you are okay with overwriting all of the old content in the `div`:

```
$('div').text(content);
```

If you do not want to wrap it inside a new `div`, use

```
$('div').append($('<div>').text(content).html());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a text node instead:

```js
var content = "<div>Text</div>";
$("body").append( document.createTextNode( content ) );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/ojn2L0vL/