# Copy word from between [wiki] word [/wiki] and add to output

Tags: jquery

I use my own created bbcode [wiki] [/wiki] so every word encapsulated between these codes will create a link to my wiki. See code below. This works great.

```
if (show_wiki_dscn == true ){

    var wiki_start = '<a class="fancywiki" href="http://www.domain.com/support/wiki-inline/';
    var wiki_end = '" data-fancybox-type="iframe"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-1x"></i></a>';

    $('div.content_body').each(function() {     
        $(this).html( $(this).html().replace( /\[wiki]/g, wiki_start ).replace( /\[\/wiki]/g, wiki_end));
    })

} else {

    var wiki_start = '<a class="pop-tooltip" href="http://www.domain.com/support/wiki/';
    var wiki_end = '" target="blank" title="Read our wiki"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-1x"></i></a>';

    $('div.content_body').each(function() {
        $(this).html( $(this).html().replace( /\[wiki]/g, wiki_start ).replace( /\[\/wiki]/g, wiki_end));
    })
}
```

Now my question. 
I would like to show the wiki "word" instead of the question mark.

So how do I copy `[wiki]word[/wiki]` and replace `<i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-1x"></i>` with the "word"

Comment: You question would be a lot clearer if you included an example of the input and what you want the output to be. Then use a capturing group in your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a single regex, and capture the word:

```
$('div.content_body').each(function() {     
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace( /\[wiki\](.*?)\[\/wiki\]/g, '<a class="fancywiki" href="http://www.domain.com/support/wiki-inline/" data-fancybox-type="iframe">$1</a>'));
})
```

I use `$1` inside the replacement string to insert it.

I also recommend you read [Is it really insecure to build HTML strings in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990899/is-it-really-insecure-to-build-html-strings-in-javascript) about your replacement method, as it's currently insecure.

Comment: Perfect. You made my day... Uh insecure, I din't know. How could I make it secure?

Comment: Perhaps instead of naively inserting the word, use some more advanced regex stuff to match and then save (`var wikiWord = $(this).html().match(thatRegex)`; then build the HTML using techniques from the other post.

Comment: That safety should be already present in the bbcode interpreter. So rather than winging it client-side, see if you can formally add `[wikw]...[/wiki]` to the server-side bb script.