# Prepend jQuery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, prepend

I have the sources for images (the urls) stored in a jQuery array. I want to prepend each source from the array into it's own collection of tags. I have something like this:

```
var images = [link1,link2,link3,etc,etc];

$('.gallery').prepend();
```

but I don't know what to put in the `.prepend().`

I need each image individually inside something like this:

```
<label class="align"><img class="thumbnail" src=""+images+""/></label>
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will create a simple template and prepend that template (DOM element) into your gallery class.

```
var images = [link1,link2,link3,etc,etc];
for( var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
  var temp = '<label class="align"><img class="thumbnail" src="'+images[i]+'"/></label>'
  $('.gallery').prepend(temp);
}
```

Does this work for what you need?

Comment: Upvote for a plain JS solution. Was updating my answer for a plain variant, not needed now. Plain JS is often (a lot) faster, specially with simple code

Answer (score 1):

You could map over the array and return a jQuery object for each:

```
var images = ['link1','link2','link3','etc','etc'];

$('.gallery').prepend(images.map(function(image){
    return $('<img class="thumbnail" />').src(image).wrap('<label class="align">').parent();
}));
```

(See [my writeup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990899/is-it-really-insecure-to-build-html-strings-in-javascript/26991020#26991020) on why not to just do a simple HTML string, even though it might be easier.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can loop through the array with [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and add the images to a string of html:

```
var images = ['link1','link2','link3','etc','etc'];

var imagesHtml = '';
$.each(images, function(index,value){
    imagesHtml += '<label class="align"><img class="thumbnail" src="'+value+'" /></label>';
});
$('.gallery').prepend( imagesHtml );
```

You can add the images to the gallery in the each loop, but changes to the DOM (simplefied: the document/html) are expensive, this way you make a large string (it's not html at this point), and only perform 1 DOM update