# lint errors blocking did some research but not successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript, tslint

- I am new to tslint and typescript.
- I am trying to fix this error.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- i did some research but not able to find solutions.
- providing code below.

(no-inner-html) app/components/sports.ts[717, 9]: Using the html() function to write a string to innerHTML is insecure: $('.tubing').html(health.title)

```or-tag-here
if (health.title == "waterS") {
      let that = this;
      let recordPlayersWeight = {};
      this.futureParrot = [];
      this.pastParrot = [];
      this.peacockService.getResponse(health.url, 'get', null)
        .subscribe(recordPlayersWeight => {
            this.gridData = recordPlayersWeight.waterDtos;
            that._recordPlayersWeightSource.recordPlayersWeight(this.gridData);
          },
          err => {
          }
        );
    }

    that.window = $("#TigerwatersPopup");
    that.window.kendoWindow({
      width: "60%",
      title: false,
      visible: false,
      resizable: false,
      actions: [],
      draggable: false,
      modal: true,
      open: function() {
        $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        that.isVisible = true;
        $('.tubing').html(health.title);
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990899/is-it-really-insecure-to-build-html-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use jQuery's `.html()` function, it's possible to accidentally add "unsafe" elements to your page, for example iframe tags or source tags. If the html you add was submitted by a malicious user (e.g. as part of a query or data entered in a form), you're giving them a way to attack you. It's a form of code injection attack (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

In your case it looks like you're just trying to put plain text into the `.tubing` element, so it's safer to do

```
$('.tubing').text( health.title );
```

What this does is it "escapes" any HTML special characters like `<` or `>` so that they appear as text rather than being treated as elements. This is safe and prevents code injection by an attacker, and will not trigger the lint rule.

Comment: thanks for your reply...I am getting another error can you tell me how to fix it Property 'waterService' cannot be declared in the constructor

Comment: That's not in the code you posted, so I can't help. Maybe ask another question. The error you get should give you a hint as to the file and line that's causing the problem.

Comment: hey its happening at this line constructor(public waterService: WATERService) can you help me