# Escape/remove <script> tags in JSON data parsed to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, string

I have a data file that contains JSON objects to load data on my site. I would like to know if there's a way to use Javascript to find and strip out any  tags that may be within paragraph content.

Edit: i'm using handlebars locally.

Example:

```
{
'foodType': 'breakfast bar',
'title': 'granola Bar',
'ingredients': 'oats, sesame seeds, sulphites, almonds <script>console.log("executed!")</script>, cashews, soy, stabilisers. May contain traces of peanuts, milk and other gluten cereals.'
},
```

I'm displaying the content like this:

```
for (var j=0; j<ingredientsList.length; j++){
var ingredients = $('<p/>');
ingredients.append(ingredientsList[j]);
$('.ingredients-sentences').append(ingredients);
}
```

How can I find the  tag in my content and remove it before I build my ingredients paragraph?

I've tried the following but feel like i'm going around in circles now:

```
if (ingredientsList.indexOf('<script>') > 0) {

var start = ingredientsList.indexOf('<script>'); 
var end = ingredientsList.indexOf('</s');

ingredientsList.slice(start, end);
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: do you really need to strip it or do you want to escape it? It's not particularly save to just remove <script> if also <script   > could be used to inject harmful code...

Comment: I'm a little bit out of my depth when it comes to cleansing content tbh. If escaping prevents injecting harmful code then that would work too.

Comment: jQuery.text() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

As cschuff says...

```
ingredients.text(ingredientsList[j]);
```