# Laravel blade escape jquery

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

In my laravel 4 project users can submit textarea data. I know I can escape user data with {{{ }}}  in my views,
But what should i do if i get the data with ajax ? It is a jquery variable i cant escape it with the brackets. For example if I handle response from ajax like :

```
$.each(response, function( key, value ) 
{
    $('#div').append('<div>'+value.notEscapedData+'<div>')
});
```

And the controller where the data comes from is for example.

```
$response = Data::all()
return $response;
```

Comment: You want HTML Escape. Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery) for great answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do it with javascript (and you will find plenty solutions on the internet. e.g. the link @Thrustmaster posted in the comments) or you can do it in Laravel.

When you use Blades triple curly braces `{{{` `}}}` it compiles to a call to `e()` (which then calls `htmlentities`)

So you can use `e('string-containing-html')` to escape the string.

You could use a [model attribute accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) for the escaping but I suppose you will need the string unescaped sometimes so here are a two other options:

### toArray()

Override the `toArray()` method in your model

```
public function toArray(){
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $array['attribute_name'] = e($array['attribute_name']);
    return $array;
}
```

This way every time the model gets converted into an array (which is used for converting it into JSON=, the property will be escaped.

### Loop over it in your controller

```
$data = Data::all();
$data->each(function($d){
    $d->attribute_name = e($d->attribute_name);
});
return Response::json($data);
```

Comment: What is the advantage of returning it as json response over returning it as a collection, thanks for the nice explanation btw.

Comment: There's no technical difference but it makes clear that the action will return json

Comment: What do you mean? If `toArray()` works when you just return the collection instead of `Response::json()`?