# how to print html tag in jquery code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, text-to-speech

I want to print the audio tag in html what should I add in my html code

```html
<script ></script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{            
  // Request 
  jQuery.getJSON
  (
    ,
    {
      prot_vers: 2, cl_login: " ", cl_app: " ", cl_pwd: " ", 
      req_voice:"heather22k", 
      req_text:$("#demo_voices_textarea").val()
    },
    function(data) 
    {
      //api response management 
      $("#demo1player").html("<audio src='"+data.snd_url+"' controls='controls' />"); 
    }      
  );
});
```

and my html code is here

```html
 <form name="Test"  method="post">
<textarea name="demo_voices_textarea" rows="4" cols="20">Hello World !</textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Create sound!">
</form>
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) as shown :-

```
$("#demo1player").text("<audio src='"+data.snd_url+"' controls='controls' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<pre>...</pre>` tag

```
$("#demo1player").html("<pre><audio src='"+data.snd_url+"' controls='controls' /></pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead `<` and `>` :

```
$("#demo1player").html("&lt;audio src='"+data.snd_url+"' controls='controls' /&gt;");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the $(element).text() function. A few days ago I've looked how to escape html in javascript. I found following Link: [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)

I think it should work for your purpose.