# .innerText() and .innerHtml() and & on IE8 not showing

Tags: jquery, html

I have this javascript code:

```
label.innerHTML = value;
$this.replaceWith(label.cloneNode(true));
```

For value I have "T00C&T". On every browser I get this value, except on IE8 where I get "T00C" only. I've tried change **innerHTML** to **text** but then it's not working on Chrome. If I use **innerText** then it's not working on Mozzila. Also I've tried **textContent** without results.

I don't know how to sync all browsers to work without checking browser version. 
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Comment: Have you got the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**supported across browsers**

Use the following Numbered HTML entity replacement for `&`:

```
& →  &#38;
```