# Decode a string not url in Javascript

Tags: javascript, deprecation-warning

I am trying to decode  a **string  not URL**.  i tried escape function which is working fine. but Escape function is deprecated now

```
var a = "mysap'fff'"; //it could be any string

var usingEscape = escape(a);
alert(usingEscape);
```

Result is : **mysap%27fff%27**  which is fine

```
var usingEncodeUri = encodeURI(a);
alert(usingEncodeUri);
```

Result is : **mysap'fff**

```
var usingEncodingUriComponemt = encodeURIComponent(a);
alert(usingEncodingUriComponemt);
```

Result is : **mysap'fff**

Now i need result which is given by escape function. Any alternate for the same

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery try this

Comment: escape still works for me

Comment: Why do you need to escape single quotes? Those are fine in URLs.

Comment: What do you need the encoding for at all? If you would tell us your actual use case (instead of just "*not url*"), we could suggest you an appropriate solution. If your only requirement is to "work like `escape`", then the solution is to use `escape`.

Answer (score 2):

You could always build your own escape function, a-la:

```
function escapeHTML(html) {
    return html
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }
```

There's also a <strike>terrible</strike> jQuery method, although it may not be cross-browser-safe and doesn't escape quotes or double quotes (which makes it kinda useless, to be honest):

```
var html = [INSERT SOME HTML HERE];
var escapedHTML = $("div.[SOME DIV]").text(html).html();
```

tl;dr: Use the first method and skip the second method unless you want semi-escaped strings.

Comment: @HituBansal Did this answer help you? If so, I'd love it if you could accept!