# jquery search function not working when string has Asterisk mark

Tags: jquery, string

When I am searching a string using the below jquery search method it is working fine, but when the strings have a '*' mark in them then it is not searching.

```
$(this).html().search(a)
```

this works fine until 'a' and '$(this).html().search(a)' does not have '*' asterisk mark.
If 'a' and '$(this).html()' both are same string with * mark then it fails.

Answer (score 0):

serach() isn't a jquery function. It's a [javascript function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp). It accepts regular expressions.
According to regular expression, * is a special character that means 0 or more occurrences of the preceding character should be matched.
Try to escape asterisks with: \\*

Comment: Thanks mauretto, the problem is $(this).html() is inside a for loop so it's not constant. Is there a way it will escape automatically if there is an asterisk?

Comment: @antnewbee edit your question with the loop, the community will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery's  `text()` to escape the output automatically.

check: http://api.jquery.com/text/ for examples.
This is also related to your question: [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)