# Using Alert() to display actual HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to use alert() or another pop-up to display actual HTML code that? For example, I have the code below:

```
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0); 
    var newNode = document.createElement('span');
    newNode.setAttribute("class", "selectedText");
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
```

I want to use an alert to display the HTML result of

```
range.surroundContents(newNode);
```

It should display something like

`<span class='selectedText'>'range will go in here'</span>.`

Which is what I want to validate.Thanks!

Comment: you could use newNode.outerHTML. it will return a string

Comment: @echopeak thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for....is outerHTML supported on all browsers

Comment: consider using `console.log` or any of the `console.*` functions for debugging instead of `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the html to a variable & alert that variable

**HTML**

```
<span class='selectedText' id ="someId">range will go in here</span>
```

**JS**

```
var a = document.getElementById("someId").outerHTML;
alert(a)
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/k5c0xha0/14/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to set the element's `text`property.

```
var htmlstring = "<span class='selectedText'>'range will go in here'</span>"
$("div.selectedText").text(htmlstring);
var htmlescaped = $("<div>").text(htmlstring).html();
```

That block there will end up with the string `&lt;span class='selectedText'&gt;'range will go in here'&lt;/span&gt;`, which is an escaped version of your html, which can be printed any way you like.

Note that this method may encounter difficulties with newlines (`\n`) and some types of whitespace.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery).