# Jquery stop rendering Html syntax escape javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Ordered list with a class named as comments. 
 So i am pushing values from my text area into a variable named **my_html_syntax**.

The code works fine the only problem is how do I stop html syntax from rendering
for example when i enter html syntax for a buttton it renders the button into my ul.

how do i escape my javascript variable  my_html_syntax

SOLVED -thanks to justinas this is how i used it .

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-    2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('button').click(function() {
function htmlEntities(str) {
 return String(str).replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}

var my_html_syntax= $('#textarea').val(); 

$('ul').append('<li>' + htmlEntities(my_html_syntax) +'</li>');


   });
      });

 </script>

</head>
<body>
<textarea id="textarea" class="textarea" rows="4" cols="50"> </textarea>

<button class="doit" id="doit" type="button" value="submit">   submit</button>

<ul class="comments" id="comments">  asd </ul>

</body>

  </html>
```

Comment: You can execute `text()` on value returned by `val()` because it's string not jQuery Object.

Comment: You can use regex to strip html like `$('#textarea').val().replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)

Comment: technically abit different since it's about appending to Ul and about how to escape a variable .

Comment: This is an bad way, use `.text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape HTML entities to be shown:

```js
function htmlEntities(str) {
  return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul').append("<li>" + htmlEntities("<a href='example.com'>LINK</a>") + "</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

**Bad ways.**

You have to use `.text()`.

```
$("<li></li>")
    .text(my_html_syntax)
    .appendTo($('.comments'));
```

Or with `.append()` :

```
$('.comments').append($("<li></li>").text(my_html_syntax));
```