# generate HTML from a set of jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to modify an HTML string (things like adding class to one of its children). In my code I have to used a `container` as a midway to ouput `$html` as a string. Does jQuery provide any function to do this?

```
  html = "<p>title</p><div><ul class='www'></ul>something</div>";
  $html = $(html);
  $html.filter('div').find('ul').addClass('xxx');
  container = $('<div></div>');
  html = container.html($html)[0].innerHTML; //output "<p>title</p><div><ul class='www xxx'></ul>something</div>"
```

Comment: I dont understand, you want to write `$html` (after adding the class) as a string instead of creating DOM elements?

Comment: yes, I want it as a string, and there is no actual DOM here.

Comment: @guradio I am asking whether I can do this without introducing a `container`

Comment: why is using a container a problem?

Comment: not a problem, just a little obsessed with always using existing function(if any)

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

There is no escape to interacting with the DOM (this is creating or selecting an existing element), the best you can try is to [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) your string but you'll need to [scape the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery) so it doesn't gets interpreted as HTML but text. Notice that `document.write` only works before the document finishes loading.

I don't know your needs but I can't think of a good use case for this, your jQuery should be better for most cases.