# JavaScript/jQuery: how to get HTML and display HTML, including tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery, and have an HTML block as follows:

```
   <div id="html-block">
       <h1>Heading 1</h1>
       <h2>Heading 2</h2>
       <h3>Heading 3</h3>
    </div>
```

Which renders as:

**Heading 1**

**Heading 2**

**Heading 3**

What I am trying to do is show what HTML was used to create this block.

If I use  `$(this).clone().insertAfter(this);` simply repeats what we see rendered, but what I actually want to see in my browser is:

```
<div id="html-block">
       <h1>Heading 1</h1>
       <h2>Heading 2</h2>
       <h3>Heading 3</h3>
 </div>
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: `document.getElementById('html-block').outerHTML`

Comment: Are you talking about having the html tags visible to the user? Try setting `text`, which will HTML-encode the passed value: `$('<div/>', { text: $(this).html() }).insertAfter(this);`. Can also be called as a function `container.text( ... )`

Comment: try ``.append()`` ?

Comment: Yes HTML tags visible in the browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to be able to do is escape the HTML before you output it so that the browser doesn't render the tags contained therein.

You can escape HTML easily using jQuery like this:

```
var escapedHtml = $('<div />').text($('#html-block').html());
```

Now you have a string with things like `&lt;div id=&quot;html-block&quot;&gt;` which you can spit out to the browser:

```
$('#html-block').after($('<pre />').html(escapedHtml));
```

All in one you could do this:

```
var $htmlBlock = $('#html-block');
$('<pre />').text($htmlBlock.html()).insertAfter($htmlBlock);
```

Comment: Perfect, escaping the HTML was what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Also see this duplicate:
[Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)

```
var entityMap = {
  "&": "&amp;",
  "<": "&lt;",
  ">": "&gt;",
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#39;',
  "/": '&#x2F;'
};

function escapeHtml(string) {
  return string.replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {
    return entityMap[s];
  });
}
```

... 
then use

```
var outer = escapeHTML($(this).clone().outerHTML);
$(outer).insertAfter(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the mapping mike.

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = $("#html-block")
var html = el[0].outerHTML.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
el.after(html)
```

Notes:

- el[0] gets the actual HTML dom element (as opposed to the jQuery-wrapped element)
- outerHTML gets the HTML of the element itself (not just its contents)
- the replace tags escape the "<" and ">" characters, which are what tells the browser to render the tags as tags and not just text.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Oh, just saw the other answers; they're better :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
str = "250m&lt;sup&gt;2&lt;/sup&gt;";
let entityMap = {
   "&lt;": "<",
   "&gt;": ">",
};
str = str.replace(/(&lt;)|(&gt;)/g, m => entityMap[m]);

console.log(str);
```