# Link not clickable in dynamically added (JQuery) row of list in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, chatterbot

I am building a chatbot that provides a link on occasion (using the Chatterbot package as a base). The link comes from python code to my HTML file from where a row is appended to the existing list using JQuery. My problem is that this link does not show up as clickable. I have tried JavaScript link() and html(). I have also tried Anchorme, Autolinker and Linkify.

This is where I am receiving the output from the chatbot:

```
$submit.done(function(statement) {
    createRow(statement);
```

And this is the code for the row creation using JQuery:

```
function createRow(text) {
var $row = $('<li class="list-group-item"></li>');
$row.text(text);
$chatlog.append($row);
}
```

This is what the output looks like.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `$row.html(text)` should work. What does `console.log(text)` show?

Comment: Be aware that setting HTML from something that can contain user input is fairly dangerous in terms of XSS.

Comment: Here is a fiddle to play with : https://jsfiddle.net/pcyf1x2c/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row.html(text)` should work if the image is anything to go by.

Comment: This worked for me. The mistake I was making was trying $row.text(text).html() which I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/374176/9521089.