# How to make "<" not interpreted in .html() using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have to generate a php file from the content of a `div`, this is working. But characters like `<` and `>` are blocking the generation.

For example :

```
<div id="test">
<p> I want to have this in my php file &lt;?php echo "tatata" ?&gt; </p>
</div>
```

I'm using the function `$("#test").html()` to get the content before to send it to a php file using `ajax`.

If I do an alert of this, I get the correct data but when I open the php file generated, I only have :

```
<div id="test">
<p> I want to have this in my php file
```

I've tried to use `&#60` instead of `&lt;` 
I dont know if the problem comes from jQuery or the php code I call with `ajax`.

But I'm sure the problem is due to the `<` and `>` characters, because when I remove them, it works correctly.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: @treyBake no. Here I want to get ALL the content (including HTML) of the test div. It's not supposed to print anything. THe content (php and HTML) will be saved in a file to be processed later, not here :)
I want to get the content as a string to save it :)

Comment: Any `<` character will be interperted as HTML by the browser. If you take the HTML of that file, store it in a `.php` file, then serve it as a `.php` file, it would execute `<?php echo ..`.

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: @Spydaxx so you want it to output as plain-text? so the PHP never gets executed?

Comment: @treyBakei yes that's what I want. I want the content of the div as pure text. But "&lt;" is supposed to be saved as "<" of course.

Comment: @Spydaxx then str_replace? did you google this?

Comment: or the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: @treyBake no. I don't know this function. I'm going to the docs.

Comment: may need to escape the entities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery/13510502

Comment: @treyBake i'll try to use str_replace in my php to see if it resolves the problem

Comment: @treyBake It works perfectly using str_replace ! Thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion of @treyBake is working perfectly.

As he suggested in the comments, the function `str_replace` solved the problem. I use it just before to create my php file and it's working.

Thank you @treyBake ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using htmlentities?

e.g.

```
echo htmlentities('&lt;sometext&gt;');
```