# Is it safe to only escape HTML instead of using a library like DOMPurify to prevent XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, security, escaping, xss

I'm currently using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12034334/962155) to escape my HTML before inserting it into a `<div>` using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in my app.

However, I noticed there are also libraries like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify), which purport to be the safer approach to escaping HTML. Except that it's approximately 1000x larger of a solution, so I'm wondering if it's necessary.

I notice that the first solution in my answer seems to work well enough. I tried entering `<script>alert('a')</script>` into the message box and it seemed to be escaped properly. For my purposes I'm only doing a couple simple markup transformations (bolding, italics, etc.).

Is what I'm doing enough, or do I need a more powerful solution like DOMPurify? I rather not add the dependency if it's not necessary.

Comment: If you're escaping the HTML anyway, and you're using React, then why aren't you just inserting it normally as text?

Comment: Just enabling some simple markdown transformations first. Like turning \*asdf\* into <strong>asdf</strong>. It's from user messages so I think I need dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: The question is are you willing to risk it? I don't think a single dependency being added is a big enough reason to justify the security risks the XSS attacks may pose.

Comment: Well it seems like many people are already using the former solution judging by the amount of upvotes the response got. Was wondering if it's insecure.

Comment: If you want to sanitize HTML tags only it's enough, otherwise you should opt for `DOMPurify`

Comment: @matrixersp: so in my case where the only place in my app I'm using dangerouslySetInnerHTML is for inserting into a div for user messages and applying the mentioned function, then I'm safe?

Comment: @RyanPeschel I think it might cause issues in the text you pass to it, you should use `DOMPurify`, also they claim to be super-fast, so you don't have to care much about the performance

Comment: I don't care about the performance really, just about limiting dependencies. I have only one frontend dependency right now (React), and I'm trying to keep it that way. Also I'm confused because in your previous message you said it'd be enough but now you're saying you think it might not be enough. Looking for something more authoritative/definite.

Comment: It depends on what you want to accept as user input. For example, blindly replacing `&`s by character entity references wouldn't work with user input containing "RESTful" URLs such as `http://example.com/whatever/x=1&y=2`. For handling cases like that (and also for the general case where you want to accept richly-formatted user input with tags), you'd need an HTML-ware sanitizer such as a full-blown SGML-based one. Simple solutions can't handle that; don' t know  if `DOMPurify` can.

Answer (score 1):

In its basic form? Yes, it is safe when used like this:

```
<p id="example"></p>
<script>
let escapedText = escapeHtml(userInput);
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = escapedText;
</script>
```

However, once you start modifying the escaped text and adding your own HTML tags to it, you may accidentally introduce a vector to XSS. Here is an example with a link specified by user input:

```
<p id="example"></p>
<script>
let escapedLink = escapeHtml(userInput);
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = `<a href="${escapedLink}">Click here</a>`;
</script>
```

This demonstrates two shortcomings:

1. The attacker could set the link to `javascript:alert(1)` and achieve XSS.
2. Legitimate links could not be inserted, as the HTML escape blocks the `/` character.

This is a simple example and **there are many *less obvious* ways to mess up badly here**. Using a good HTML purifier library, such as DOMPurify, not only helps against XSS and similar vulnerabilities, but also lets you implement or even accept user input for custom HTML.