# Display image from array of pathnames

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My goal is to display an image on the page from the one of the folders, for example `~/Content/Images/img_1.jpg`.
The image paths are saved inside an array that I successfully fetch from a DB. What I am struggling with is the fact that there are special characters in the passed command.

So I'd have something like `@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/img_1.jpg")`
to pass in the DB field and when it gets passed to JQuery `.html()` it doesn't work properly and gives a 404. I looked into escaping the characters but I don't think that works. This might be a bad way of doing the whole thing though, so I am open to ideas on how to facilitate that dynamic image loading...

EDIT: I have figured a bit out. The DB will hold only the image name, not the full path. So only the escaping the pathname characters in JS in HTML context are left.

`"<img src=/Content/Images/" (escape characters here) + metadata.imgSrc + " alt=" + metadata.title + " >";`

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I escaped the string inside using the mapping from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery) answer.

So I got:

`"<img src=&#x2F;Content&#x2F;Images&#x2F;" + metadata.imgSrc + " alt=" + metadata.title + " >";`

With the image being placed in the respective directory.