# Prevent script tags from executing on page load with form get

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a search page which has a form.

```
<form method="get" action="/search">
  <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
</form>
```

When I am loading the url with the search querystring, I am getting an alert, I would like to avoid this.

```
http://localhost/search?search=<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

I tried this but it isn't working,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var search_value = $('#search').val();
if(search_value !== '')
  {
   search_value = search_value.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
   $('#search').val(search_value);
  }
});
```

I would like to process the string before the loading, but I am unable to, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Helpful discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Comment: @RyanWildry sorry if I wasn't clear in my post, the issue is about which event to use to process the string, the document.ready is loading after the alert, I need to process the string before the alert loads.

Comment: Where specifically is the line `http://localhost/search?search=<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>` in relation to the `$(document).ready()`?