# How to sanitize ajax success response Polaris scan XSS

Tags: ajax, coverity

I am running Synopsys' Coverity scanning tool and it says the following function needs to sanitize "success".  I have tried DomPurify, DomParser etc and all it does is break the UI.  Any help would be wonderful.

```
$.ajax({
   url: window.paramFormRoleView.UrlGetIsoData,
   success: function (response) {
     bindIsosDropDown(response);
   }
 });
```

Here is the function for bindIsosDropDown

function bindIsosDropDown(isoData) {

```
var isoDropDownHtml = "";

if (window.existingAssociatedIsos !== null && window.existingAssociatedIsos !== "") {

    var existingAssociatedIsosArr = window.existingAssociatedIsos.split(',').map(Number);

    $(isoData).each(function (index, iso) {

        isoDropDownHtml += '<option value="' + iso.IsoId + '"' + (($.inArray(iso.IsoId, existingAssociatedIsosArr) > -1) ? 'Selected' : '') + '>' + iso.LegalName + '</option>';

    });

} else {

    $(isoData).each(function (index, iso) {

        isoDropDownHtml += '<option value="' + iso.IsoId + '">' + iso.LegalName + '</option>';

    });

}

$("#ddlIsoList").html(isoDropDownHtml);

$(".multiselect").multiselect({ noneSelectedText: 'Select ISO' });

manageIsosAndRoles();
```

}

Comment: What is the definition of `bindIsosDropDown`?

Comment: It pulls in options into a dropdown.  The options are checkboxes and it allows a admin to select a sub role for the user.

Comment: I believe the problem is in `bindIsosDropDown` since it takes `response` as a parameter.  Please add its definition to your question (click "Edit").

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

The `bindIsosDropDown` function is insecure.  It accepts `isoData` as a parameter, but that comes directly from the network, so it is "tainted" (potentially under attacker control).  It then concatenates elements of `isoData` to make HTML in these lines of code (and elsewhere):

```
$(isoData).each(function (index, iso) {
    isoDropDownHtml += '<option value="' + iso.IsoId + '"' + ...;
});
```

If `isoData` is, for example (in JSON syntax):

```
[
  { IsoId: "\"><script>alert('Gotcha!')</script><option value=\"" }
]
```

then `isoDropDownHtml` will be:

```
<option value=""><script>alert('Gotcha!')</script><option value="" ...
```

and consequently the browser will execute the attacker payload (here just an `alert` message, but it could be any malicious code).

### Solution

Typically, you want to *escape* any HTML metacharacters that might be in the tainted data so they cannot break out of the syntactic context, which in this case is a double-quoted attribute value.  The question [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery) has several suggestions for specific ways to do that.

Assuming you use one of those suggestions, and therefore have a function called `escapeHtml` that will escape HTML metacharacters, you can use it like this:

```
$(isoData).each(function (index, iso) {
    isoDropDownHtml += '<option value="' + escapeHtml(iso.IsoId) + '"' + ...;
    //                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

If you now work through what happens with the example `isoData` from before, you will see that the `IsoId` gets properly encoded as an HTML attribute value, and consequently no executable Javascript gets delivered.

Note that you have to escape tainted data like this *everywhere* in the application that might handle it.  It is not enough to fix one instance, or even all of the instances that Coverity (or any tool) can detect.  If the code in the question is typical of the application, there are probably many more places that are vulnerable, so a careful and systematic review is warranted.